# Linux - How to delete routing table all at once?

Tags: linux

Is there a quick way to delete routing table in linux, my `route` looks like this:

```
SOLVED
```

I want to delete all except the one from `br-lan` interface. Is there a quick way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use iproute2 `ip route` to output your routes and

```
ip route show | grep -v 192.168.1 | sed -e 's/.*/ip route del &/' > /tmp/clearroutes.sh
bash /tmp/clearroutes.sh
```

*Better read /tmp/clearroutes.sh before executing.*

Comment: Thanks it works great

Comment: plus, this is a general method with very simple tools, that works for nearly everything similar.